# Unable to create outlook email draft using powershell on Outlook application

Tags: php, powershell, outlook

I have a requirement to prepare outlook email draft and open it in Outlook.

I have created a PHP form to run supply variables to a PowerShell which invokes outlook methods and creates the email.

When I execute the PowerShell as below

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\wamp\www\bizops\prepare_email.ps1 >> C:\wamp\www\bizops\log.log
```

It works perfectly.

But when I place the above line in a batch file and call it in PHP Script,

```
$mail_string="c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\wamp\www\bizops\outlook_mail.bat";
exec($mail_string);
```

it gives me below error:

```
 New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
 {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 
 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 
 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).At C:\wamp\www\bizops\prepare_email.ps1:25 char:7
 + $ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
 +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

my PowerShell code looks like (Section which throws this error)

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$ns = $ol.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$Mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.Recipients.Add($mail_to_list)  
$mail.Subject = $mail_subject
$mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = $deliverAt
$Mail.HTMLBody = "SOME HTML TEXT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it took so long to find a resolution as error was not clear. There was confusion if the issue is due to permission miss match or something else.

I am glad I was able to find the solution of this.

We need to run httpd through a valid user(You may want to create a separate user t to run your tasks). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj0WG.png)

Hope screenshot will make it clear

Answer (score 1):

> But when I place the above line in a batch file and call it in PHP Script,

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

As a workaround you may consider using EWS if you deal with Exchange profiles only, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Or Outlook REST API which is available for Office 365 users, see [Get Started with Mail, Calendar, and Contacts REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted).

Also you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Or just any other third-party wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

Comment: A statement from Microsoft about not using Office in a non-interactive environment. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: Yeah, you can find the link in my post.

Answer (score 0):

`CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE` most likely means the two processes are running in different security contexts - the COM system refuses to marshal the calls in this case.

Is either app running with elevated security privileges (Rus As Administrator)?

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

Is there any to check if the two processes are running in different security contexts?
Can you suggest ways to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Trapping the exception and processing this particular COM code (0x80080005) is probably the best way.